# Editing a Body Mapping template to pass Woocommerce webhooks to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, woocommerce, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webhooks

I have been trying to get a Woocommerce webhook to pass through API Gateway and output individual pieces of data outputted in the console. The problem being, I just cannot get the Body Mapping template configured properly to pass the body through to the Lambda function. I eventually want to use these event objects to be passed into DynamoDB but I am just logging them in the console for now.

The body data outputs fine using the test event within AWS Lambda when using the standard webhook body, using an example such as http://myjson.com/18afwp

Here is my Lambda code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback, err) => {
callback(null, event.order_key);
if (err) console.log('JSON Pass Fail');  // an error occurred
else     console.log(event.order_key); // successful response
};
```

Which displays the result:
"wc_order_5a64ab355c2b2" and again in the console log 2018-01-22T21:45:22.560Z  8c417061-ffgd-11e7-805b-f57d6e6be228    wc_order_5a64ab355c2b2

For the Body Mapping Template I have tried a few variants but settling on the standard Method Request Passthrough but I think the body part just needs tweaking to allow the body to pass through. Here are the contents of the standard body mapping template https://pastebin.com/gjZaxBTW

In Cloudwatch, the logs just come back as undefined when a Woocommerce webhook is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, the successful body mapping template is shown below that passes the header and body data through to Lambda. These objects can then be accessed using `event.body.order_key` format.

I had originally tried adding each line of the headers shown in Woocommerce admin under Webhooks that displays the Webhook output. But if you look at your Cloudwatch logs you will see extra headers are added by Cloudfront and more than is listed in Wordpress.

```
{
"body" : $input.json('$'),
"headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
}
}
```

This uses the **Request Body Passthrough** option

```
When there are no templates defined (recommended)
```